# RCP4 Coolbar positioning

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I would like to add a banner underneath the toolbar in my application.  From what I've read it looks like the easiest way in RCP 4 would be to use a coolbar.  However, I cannot find any examples which show how to do it.  Is it possible to create a coolbar and have it display below the toolbar menu?

Comment: What do you mean by 'RCP 4'? Are you talking about Eclipse or one of the other Java IDEs?

Comment: I am talking about Eclipse RCP4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse e4 the main tool bars are called the 'TrimBars'. In the Application.e4xmi editor you can choose to have TrimBars at the top (below the menu), left, right or bottom of a Trimmed Window.